# SQL bulk collect and count

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a database that has id's of people inside and money that they owe..
a person can be found in de database several times on diffrent rows.

I need to collect all people who have an amount open higher then 140 and get all their information in the table (table name is money).

I tried using a select statement using having count(Cashdue) > 140 but he won't allow that on a bulk collect.

Any idea how I can bulk collect information while at the same time counting only the people who's total amount of money is above 140?

Thanks in advance.

```
DECLARE
  Type type_coll_number
  is table of money.userid%type;

  t_moneydue type_coll_number;
BEGIN
  select money.userid
  bulk collect into t_moneydue
  from money
  group by userid
  having count(Cashdue) > 140;

  for i in 1 .. t_moneydue.count
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(t_moneydue(i));
  end loop;
END;
```

Comment: You probably want having sum(cashdue) > 140 rather than count

Comment: Omg, I can't believe i didn't figure that out -.-

Comment: yea, I get that too. you stare at a problem for too long you don't see the blinding flash of the obvious :)

Answer (score 1):

Turning my comment into an answer :-)

You probably want having sum(cashdue) > 140 rather than count

Answer (score 0):

Just place it inside another query:

```
select userid
bulk collect into t_moneydue
from (
  select money.userid 
  from money
  group by userid
  having sum(Cashdue) > 140
);
```